# regular expression issue in internet explorer 8

Tags: javascript, regex, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to do the following in the console of IE8

```
new RegExp(/(^(([+]?((([0-9\u0660-\u0669]+)([\,\.\-]?[\s]?))+))+){4,255}$)|(^[]{0,255}$)/).test('1234')
```

and I am getting the following error `"Expected ']'` in regular expression" but whenever I try this on Firefox it returns true with no errors what so ever.

I am unable to figure where in the regular expression, the problem lies. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Firefox: *invalid quantifier*

Comment: What is `^[]` supposed to do?

Comment: so that it would accept empty "" string

Comment: This makes no sense: `^[]{0,255}$`.  You can have 255 of nothing between the beginning and end of the string??  Please describe what you are trying to match (and give sample data).

Comment: this expression should accept a number from 4 to 255 digits or nothing at all like so new RegExp(/(^(([+]?((([0-9\u0660-\u0669]+)([\,\.\-]?[\s]?))+))+){4,255}$)|(^[]{0,255}$)/).test('');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new RegExp(/(^(([+]?((([0-9\u0660-\u0669]+)([\,\.\-]?[\s]?))+))+){4,255}$)|(^[ ]{0,255}$)/).test('1234')
```

Put a space between `[ ]` at: `(^[ ]{0,255}$)/)`

Comment: Woludn't that match up to 255 spaces?

Answer (score 3):

Why not using (^$) to match the empty string?

```
new RegExp(/(^(([+]?((([0-9\u0660-\u0669]+)([\,\.\-]?[\s]?))+))+){4,255}$)|(^$)/).test('')
//true
new RegExp(/(^(([+]?((([0-9\u0660-\u0669]+)([\,\.\-]?[\s]?))+))+){4,255}$)|(^$)/).test('1234')
//true
new RegExp(/(^(([+]?((([0-9\u0660-\u0669]+)([\,\.\-]?[\s]?))+))+){4,255}$)|(^$)/).test('abc')
//false
```

That is, unless you need to match from 0 to 255 spaces along with the number part.

Comment: I really cant remember why. I think I have tried this but for some reason I needed the ^[ ]{0,255}$ to be available

Comment: That is the worst problem with regular exceptions, eghm... expressions ;> Once written, no one can understand them, even the author. And when, after years of studying, earning a PhD on it, you can finally understand what it does match, you do not understand why it should match that. Or maybe it should not?

Comment: @SWilk: I am not sure if `[]` is valid regex in JS, but I am sure the specs have the syntax specification.